# Inequality Property

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Is it generally true that for a,b,c,d in $\mathbb{R}$ and $>0$ that If $a<b$ and $c<d$ then $a-c < b-d$?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try  any example?

Comment: No it's not always true

Comment: Take $a=c=1, b=d=2$. Then $a-c=0=b-d.$

Comment: I have to show $\frac{12}{n}-\frac{8}{n^{2}}<1$ Now, i am thinking of some bounds on n , to simply it. If $n > 4(2)$ then first term is less than $3/2$. and if $n>8(2)$ the second term is less than $1/2$. Now, if n satisfies both these conditions so can i write $\frac{12}{n}-\frac{8}{n^{2}}<\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2} =1 $.

Comment: If $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ then $12/n-8/n^2<1$ iff $12n-8<n^2$ iff $28<n^2-12n+36=(n-6)^2$ iff $\sqrt {28}<|n-6|\in \Bbb Z$ iff $6\le |n-6|$ iff $n\ge 12.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO. If $x=b-a>0$ and $y=d-c>0$ then $x,y$ can be $any$ positive values so you $cannot$ conclude that $y<x.$ And $a-c<b-d\iff d-c<b-a\iff y<x.$